# Print with POS printers through USB using android framework

Tags: java, android

Help me, I want connect pos machine with my android app through usb for print page. it is connecting properly with my app but print option not working.if anyone know this so plz tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Star SDK, http://www.starmicronics.com/support/sdkdocumentation.aspx
It might be of help